# extract numeric value from value stored in another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I extract numeric part from value stored in another variable ?

For example:

```
 var a=some_string ;
```

Now I want to extract numeric value of a and store it in another variable .

Comment: how does your some_string look like. you could probably use parseInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt. Again it depends on the format of your string

Comment: @unikorn My string is "submit1" and it changes every time

Comment: changes to what? does the format remain the same. for e.g submit1 to submit3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example--

```
var a='kjh56SS';
var b='';
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(!isNaN(a.charAt(i))){
         b=b+a.charAt(i);
    }
}
alert(b);
```

Demo-- http://jsfiddle.net/mwkn4c8t/

Comment: Solution looks dumb and inefficient without regex !! You can go for regex answers if you want!!